# Carregar uma tabela dinamicamente com ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, jquery-datatables

Eu estou tentando montar uma tabela fazendo uma requisição ao servidor e popula-la com o retorno.

O retorno do servidor esta correto, mas quando entra na `function(data)`, percebi que ele carrega toda a minha pagina `html`, já tentei jogar o `ajax` direto no `$(document).ready`, e depois usar a forma que esta em abaixo, usando o `load`, porem, nenhum dos dois estão funcionando.

```
$("#table_horde").Load(
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/Horde/List/",
         success: function (data) {

             var cols = "";

             for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                 cols += "<tr>";
                 cols += "<td>" + data[i].NomeHorda + "</td>";
                 cols += "<td>" + data[i].Limit + "</td>";
                 cols += "<td><a href='#' onclick='atualizar'(" + data[i].IdHorde + ")' data-target='#janelaHordaCadastro' data-toggle='modal'>Atualizar</a></td>";
                 cols += "<td><a href='#' onclick='excluir'(" + data[i].IdHorde + ")'>Excluir</a></td>";
                 cols += "</td>";
             }

             $("#table_horde tbody").empty();
             $("#table_horde tbody").append(cols);
             $("#qtdRegistro").html(data.length);
         },
         error: function (ex) {
             alert("Erro: " + ex.status);
         }
     })
);
```

Meu `Controller` está da seguinte forma:

```
public ActionResult List() { 
    return View("List", ListinerHorde()); 
} 

private List<HordeList> ListinerHorde() {
  var list = new List<HordeList>();
  HordeRepository hr = new HordeRepository(); 

  foreach (var h in hr.FindAll()) {
   var model = new HordeList(); 
   model.NameHorde = h.NameHorde; 
   model.Limit = h.Limit; 
   list.Add(model); 
  } 

  return list; 
}
```

Veja abaixo a imagem do retorno:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como está o retorno do seu `controller`?

Comment: Note que nesta linha `cols += "</td>";` você está fechando o elemento `td`, quando deveria ser um `tr`

Comment: É verdade @Randrade, não havia reparado... Corrigi, mas o erro continua. a controller esta´retornando a lista de registro do banco corretamente

Comment: Poste um exemplo, se possível. No console (F12) aparece algum erro?

Comment: Eu chamo esse metodo na controller e no console não aparece erro nenhum, pelo contrario... me da status 200.
Mas acho que meu problema é aqui "function (data)", ta carregando toda a minha DOM nessa função

 Não to conseguindo postar o codigo, é muito grande @Randrade

Comment: coloque um `console.log(data)` acima de `var cols = "";`. Pode ser o formato de retorno do `controller`, por isso acho interessante adicionar o seu `controller` também

Comment: @Randrade
        public ActionResult List()
        {
           return View("List", ListinerHorde());
        }
 private List<HordeList> ListinerHorde()
        {
            var list = new List<HordeList>();
                HordeRepository hr = new HordeRepository();
                foreach (var h in hr.FindAll())
                {
                    var model = new HordeList();
                    model.NameHorde = h.NameHorde;
                    model.Limit = h.Limit;
                    list.Add(model);                }
                     return list;
        }

Comment: Você está retornando uma `View()`, e não uma lista. Se a sua `View()` List possui somente a tabela, você apenas precisa fazer um `.html(data)` ao invés do `for()`. Caso queira utilizar o `For()`, você não retornaria uma `View()` e sim um JSON. Poste como está a sua `View()` List que irei elaborar as duas respostas

Comment: poderia mostrar o que está trazendo no data?  console.log(data);

Comment: @DouglasJuliao data = "<!DOCTYPE html>
↵<html>
↵<head>
↵    <meta name="viewport" />
↵    <title>Listagem de Hordas</title>
↵
↵    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ma

Comment: O problema então é no Controller mesmo, você precisa trazer um JSON na resposta, não é para vir esse html, da ma olhada no seu foreach da lista

Answer (score 2):

Em seu `Controller` você está retornando uma `View`, mas em seu `Ajax` você está esperando uma lista.

Uma solução seria somente retornar a lista para a `View`, com isso, crie uma Action para retornar o JSON. Neste caso eu chamei de `ListaJson()` apenas para você entender melhor, mas pode colocar o nome que desejar.

```
public ActionResult ListaJson() { 
     var lista = ListinerHorde();
     return Json(lista , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Feito isso, apenas altera a URL do seu `Ajax`, desta forma:

```
 url: "/Horde/ListaJson/",
```

Agora, caso queira retornar a `View`, você não precisa montar a tabela no front-end, e sim adicionar o HTML retornado, um exemplo seria isso:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/Horde/List/",
     success: function (data) {
        //Coloque aqui o local onde a View deverá ocupar
        $("#table_horde").html(data);
     },
     error: function (ex) {
         alert("Erro: " + ex.status);
     }
});
```

Apenas lembre de alterar o `$("#table_horde").html(data);` para o local onde a `View` deverá ocupar.

Comment: Eu coloquei do jeito que vc falou, mas ele duplicou a minha pagina...


data = "<!DOCTYPE html>
↵<html>
↵<head>
↵    <meta name="viewport" />
↵    <title>Listagem de Hordas</title>
↵
↵    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ma

Comment: Sim, porque você está retornando uma página inteira. A `View` que está o código `Ajax` é a mesma que a que você está chamando (Horde/List)?

Comment: Sim é a mesma view, mas eu não carrego só a tabela, tem outras coisas dentro da minha pagina tbm... area de cadastro...

Comment: Então, você não conseguirá o que deseja na mesma forma. Crie uma nova Action retornando o Json, da forma da minha resposta e altere a `url` do seu Ajax. Fazendo isso, deve funcionar normalmente

Comment: @Mfilho_19 Editei a resposta

Comment: Mas se eu mudar e fazer funcionar dessa forma, ele não vai perder os dois links que estão no registro? Em cada linha eu tenho um link de atualizar e excluir, se eu só chamar uma lista pela controller, ele não vai inserir esses dois links, não é?

Comment: Ele vai inserir normalmente. O que é necessário ver é como você está trabalhando com eventos dinâmicos. Mas teste e me fale o resultado

Comment: Nada... Some a pagina inteira
só mostra 
0 
NameHorde "Teste"
Limit 23

Comment: @Mfilho_19 Poste como está a sua `View` na pergunta

Comment: Consegui!!!!

Tava faltando add dataType: "json", hehehe
Obrigadão brother!!

Comment: @Mfilho_19 Esqueci deste detalhe, sorry.